# Postfix: How to secure port 25?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

How can I secure port 25 in postfix/dovecot? Right now, I can send internal email through telnet without login. For example:

```
telnet mydomain.com 25
MAIL FROM:<me@mydomain.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<you@mydomain.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
```

Right now, everyone can send emails without login.
All I want is that, emails can only be sent when user logged in.

How can I make it something like "Relay access denied" if I am not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the postfix `mynetworks` option. You probably want to set it to 127.0.0.1/32, that way only programs running on your server can send mail without logging in first.

Comment: I still can do a telnet outside of my network. And it succeed.